# Parse CURL SOAP response

Tags: php, soap, curl

I am accessing a SOAP server via CURL (Its the only way that PHP would connect). This is the response that I'm receiving:

```
<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:header>
    <a:action s:mustunderstand="1">PublicApi/IPropertyService/CreatePropertyResponse</a:action>
</s:header>
<s:body>
    <createpropertyresponse xmlns="PublicApi">
        <createpropertyresult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi.Property" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <message xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">Successfully completed the operation</message>
            <result xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">0</result>
            <transactiondate xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">2013-05-15T04:07:48.6565312Z</transactiondate>
            <b:propertyid>55</b:propertyid>
        </createpropertyresult>
    </createpropertyresponse>
</s:body>
```

I'm trying to pull the content of:

```
<message xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">Successfully completed the operation</message>
<result xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">0</result>
<b:propertyid>55</b:propertyid>
```

But I can't figure out how to parse it. I've tried "simplexml_load_string" put that throws a bunch of errors such as "namespace warning : xmlns: URI PublicApi is not absolute"

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a standard soap client library? 
i.e. Zend Soap Client http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html
NB: You dont need to use the whole MVC, just that soap client library

Comment: If the format is always pretty much the same, preg_match() would do it for you.

Comment: Also is the soap server sending valid responses?  Can you validate with SoapUI (free download) http://www.soapui.org

Comment: @EddieJaoude I have checked it. It shows as a valid response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but if the format of the response is always roughly the same, the following might work for you:

```
?php
// the message would come from somewhere else; I hard code it to test the expression that follows:
$msg='<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:header>
    <a:action s:mustunderstand="1">PublicApi/IPropertyService/CreatePropertyResponse</a:action>
</s:header>
<s:body>
    <createpropertyresponse xmlns="PublicApi">
        <createpropertyresult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi.Property" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <message xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">Successfully completed the operation</message>
            <result xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">0</result>
            <transactiondate xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EfxFramework.PublicApi">2013-05-15T04:07:48.6565312Z</transactiondate>
            <b:propertyid>55</b:propertyid>
        </createpropertyresult>
    </createpropertyresponse>
</s:body>';

// here comes the actual parsing:
$reg1='/<message [^>]*>([^<]*)</';
$reg2='/<result [^>]*>([^<]*)</';
preg_match($reg1, $msg, $m);
print "message: ". $m[1]."\n";
preg_match($reg2, $msg, $m);
print "result: ".$m[1]."\n";
?>
```

Result of the above:

```
message: Successfully completed the operation
result: 0
```

Explanation:

`[^>]*>` : "any number of characters that are NOT `>`, followed by `>`

`([^<]*)`   : "'capture' all characters that are NOT `<`. return them in `$m[1]`

I hope this helps.